# CardEmulation getServices method return null so that Null pointer exception occurs NFC functionality

Tags: java, android, nfc, lib-nfc

`CardEmulation.getServices(CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT).isEmpty()`

above line of my code get NullPointer Exception, attempting to use isEmpty() method on null value. kindof.
What could be causes for this exeception. How to resolve it?

I am expecting why this error occurs, what could be the issues for that. Issue might be Hardware issue orElse Software bug issue. Need clarification on that.